# How can i get starting offset and lenth of logical drives?

Tags: c#, c++, wmi, storage

I need to get starting offsets(from the start of the disc in bytes or in sectors), length and drive letters and all logical drives in the system. How can i do this? Better via WMI..

I know that there is WMI class [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it can give me letters, and i can get partition where the logical drive located via [association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (wich have offset property)but on one partition there can be some logical drives, so i will unable to calculate it all starting offsets.